# Characters encoding in the server console fo JBoss

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

server outputs in console:

```
 System.out.println("метод выполнен " + p.getName());
```

result:

> 11:20:37,696 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) ьхЄюф т√яюыэхэ
>   Adam

How to setup Jboss encoding for propper console output?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the encoding on the `console-handler`. You can use the following CLI command or use the web console to change the `encoding` attribute on the `console-handler`.

```
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=encoding, value="UTF-8")
```